# Problems Connecting to WFS using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, wfs

I cannot connect to this Web Feature Service using ArcGIS Pro even though it is public:
https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wosis_latest.map

I also tried https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wosis_latest.map&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities
error message:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @IanTurton the correct syntax URL works, you have two question marks.   this works: `https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wosis_latest.map&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: fyi this works in QGIS with a strong internet connection, as there is a lot of data behind the wfs

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I add New WFS Server and get the error message - We are unable to connect to...I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

I had no trouble connecting to that WFS using ArcGIS Pro 2.7.2 and this service URL:

https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wosis_latest.map&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

I followed the instructions at [Add WFS services](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/services/add-wfs-services.htm#):

[image]

It only took a few seconds to add the WFS server connection, see the data at that connection and then add one of the datasets to a map.